# Save to LocalStorage on a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I've script two script that i want to merge as one  . Script 1 is for checking if email and password is right it brings out a success message "Correct" and it logs you in. Script 2 is what i use to store the email and password in a localstorge

Script 1

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form1").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",

        url: "log.asp",
        data: data,
  success: function(data) {
      $('#log_msg').html(data);

    var result = $.trim(data);

    if(result==="Correct"){
       window.location = 'source.asp';

    }
  }

});
});
});
```

Script 2

```
$(function() {
  var
    $email = $('#email'),
    $password = $('#password'),
    localEmail = localStorage.getItem("eaddress"),
    localPwd = localStorage.getItem("pwd");


  // SAVE VARIABLES TO LOCAL STORAGE
  $('#form1').on('submit', function() {
    localStorage.setItem("eaddress", $email.val());
    localStorage.setItem("pwd", $password.val());
  });

});
```

Now i want to merge the two together that it should only save the email and password in the localstorge if the success message is equal
to `"Correct"` and also logs you in

Comment: Saving passwords in localstorage is not save!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Never** ever store passwords on the client!
2. **Never** store passwords unencrypted!
3. To store the email address in the localStorage you can use this snippet:

   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#form1").on('submit',function(event){
       event.preventDefault();

   ```
   var data = $(this).serialize();
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "log.asp",
     data: data,

     success: function(data) {
       $('#log_msg').html(data);
       var result = $.trim(data);
       if(result==="Correct"){
         localStorage.setItem('eaddress', $('#email').val());
       }
     }
   });
   ```

   });
   });

**Note:** You have to cleanup the localStorage yourself. If you want to store the data for further identification use a sessionId in a cookie or use the sessionStorage for saving temporary data.

**Edit:** To submit the form after page load you can try something like this:

```
$(function(){
  var eAddr = localStorage.getItem('eaddress');
  if (eAddr !== null) {
    $('#email').val(eAddr);
    $('#form1').trigger('submit');
  }
});
```

**Note:** If you store the password encrypted on the client and submit it trough the form, the authentication process is quiet insecure.

I think your authentication design is wrong. You should use an authentication cookie (like a session cookie) and validate it on the server side. Without submitting a form every time a page loads nor storing credentials on the client side.

Comment: In addition to point 1 and 2. Saving the user password unencrypted and on the client-side result in security vulnerabilities, although these are easy to solve for example by saving the passwords with a SHA encryption on a database.

Comment: Like David said, store passwords only on the server. Point 1 and 2 are both an absolute no-go. To encrypt the password on the server side I need to know what language you're using. Usually passwords should be encrypted with a bcrypt algorithm.

Comment: Now i want to auto submit the form when the localstorage contains an email address, please how do i do that?

Comment: I've added a snipped to the original answer. But!! do not do that. You should inform yourself about authentication process. The way you build your system is a highly insecure way!